# Can Stripe / Laravel cashier do a one-time payment with a trial period?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I have Stripe working just fine for one-off payments with intent using `$user->invoiceFor(...)`, but I would like to add trial days like below.

```
$user->invoiceFor($desc, $price)->trialDays(30);
```

But using trial days only appears to work with a subscription. Does anyone know how to delay the charge/invoice for days on a one-time payment?

Comment: Could you please explain why you need such a function? I find it a little strange to charge your customers first, and then provide them with a trial period. I believe trial periods exist so that customers can decide if they want to pay or not.

Comment: You can't associate a trial to a one-time payment, no. What you're actually describing sounds like a way to schedule payments, which isn't possible either. You'd need to build your own logic to handle that.

Comment: I have a subscription with 30 days trial and a lifetime pay once option so for me it’s weird to offer a trial period on a subscription plan and not a trial on the lifetime one-time payment plan. I’m guessing I will have to find another way like allowing full access for a limited time and then lock down the features after a set period? But it would have been so much easier to just add invoiceFor($desc, $price)->trialDays(30) :-(

Comment: @JonathanSteele I wonder why can't we associate a trial with a one-time payment, why is this an unreasonable idea?

Comment: @jonathansteel Exactly this 